# mvc why jquery is not executing

Tags: jquery

JQuery is not working for me in this view. It fires the alert "it got here" and "it got here 2" but not `$("#PurchaseAmount").val('20');`
sandwiched in between the two alerts (or anything else). Can anyone help? Thanks.

```
@model StockHoldings.Models.Investments

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>    
</head>


}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Investments</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LastName, (SelectList)ViewBag.LastNames)


                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Fund, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Fund, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Fund, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PurchaseDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PurchaseDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PurchaseDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Shares, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Shares, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Shares, new { id = "sharesID", name = "Shares", htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Shares, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PurchasePrice, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PurchasePrice, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PurchasePrice, new { id = "purchasepriceID", name = "PurchasePrice", htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PurchasePrice, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PurchaseAmount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PurchaseAmount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PurchaseAmount, new { id = "purchaseamountID", name = "PurchaseAmount", htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PurchaseAmount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")

</div>


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
        alert('It got here');
        $("#PurchaseAmount").val('20');
        alert("It got here 2");
        //$("#PurchasePrice").blur(function () {
        //    alert("Handler for .blur() called.");
        //});

        $("#Shares,#PurchasePrice").keyup(function (e) {
        var q = $("#Shares").val();
        alert('q' + q);
        var p = $("#PurchasePrice").val();
        alert('p' + p);

        if (q && p) {
        if (!isNaN(q) && !isNaN(p)) {
            result = parseFloat(q) * parseFloat(p);
            alert('result ' + result);
        }
        }
        $("#PurchaseAmount").val(result);

        });
        });


    </script>
    }
```

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: open the console in your browser and check for errors

Comment: I don't think you should load jquery 1.10.1 **and** the latest...

Comment: That didn't do it.

Comment: what if you do $("#purchaseamountID").val('20'); ?